# Condition for independend subspaces can be simplified?

Tags: linear-algebra

In the linear algebra of Kenneth Hoffman, page 209 he state the lemma about independent subspaces $W_i$ of vector space $V$:

> Lemma. Let $\mathrm{V}$ be a finite-dimensional vector space. Let $\mathrm{W}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{k}}$ be subspaces of $\mathrm{V}$ and let $\mathrm{W}=\mathrm{W}_1+\cdots+\mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{k}}$. The following are equivalent.
> (a) $\mathrm{W}_1, \ldots, \mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{k}}$ are independent.
> (b) For each $\mathrm{j}, 2 \leq \mathrm{j} \leq \mathrm{k}$, we have
> $$
> \mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{j}} \cap\left(\mathrm{W}_1+\cdots+\mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{j}-1}\right)=\{0\} \text {. }
> $$
> (c) If $\mathbb{B}_{\mathrm{i}}$ is an ordered basis for $\mathrm{W}_{\mathrm{i}}, 1 \leq \mathrm{i} \leq \mathrm{k}$, then the sequence $\mathbb{B}=$ $\left(\left(_1, \ldots, B_{\mathbf{k}}\right)\right.$ is an ordered basis for $\mathrm{W}$.

My question is about (b) that I think the requirement is stronger, we can only require $W_1\cap (W_2+W_3+...+W_l)=\{0\}$ is enough?

Without loss of generality, suppose $k=3$, we have $W_1\cap \left( W_2+W_3 \right) =\left\{ 0 \right\} $, then I state that we have $$W_2\cap \left( W_1+W_3 \right) =\left\{ 0 \right\} \tag{1}.$$
Since if we don't have eq(1), then we will have $v_2=v_1+v_3,v_i\in W_i$, hence $v_1=v_2-v_3$, hence $W_1\cap \left( W_2+W_3 \right) \ne \left\{ 0 \right\} $. For the same reason we will have $W_3\cap \left( W_1+W_2 \right) =\left\{ 0 \right\} $. Hence we have that each $W_j$ intersects the sum of the other subspaces $W_i$ only in the zero vector, hence equivalent to (a). So my question is that we can change (b) into $W_1\cap (W_2+W_3+...+W_l)=\{0\}
$ is enough?

Comment: no, it cannot be simplified as the given statements are **equivalent** to the condition of independent subsapces, b) is not stronger than a), its the same thing

Comment: @Masacroso Is there something wrong with my reasoning?

Comment: (1) doesn’t hold: what happens if $W_2=W_3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$W_1\cap (W_2+W_3+...+W_l)=\{0\}$ is not enough, take $W_2=W_3=\cdots=W_l$ and any $W_1$ that is disjoint then you can see clearly that this is a counter example.

With the condition given in the book, it is, loosely saying, a new subspace is 'genuinely new'.

I think your misunderstood the statement, the statement is not that $W_i\cap (W_2+W_3+...+W_{i-1}+W_{i+1}+\cdots+W_l)=\{0\}$ for all $i$ but $W_i\cap (W_1+...+W_{i-1})=\{0\}$ for all $i$.